# How to style/display this array in this way ? - CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, css

I am learning React. I am working on a Demo workspace - [Demo Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/lxok2qw6m7)

I have a filtered state variable which has all the filtered items from dropdown. I am able to show this filtered state variable as an array (as you can see in pre variable)

[image: Filtered shown as array]

I want to show this as a style in the page (instead of an array). I want to show this like this - image [image: This is what I am trying to achieve]. I want to show the filtered state variable like this

```
<div>
<div>id: val0,val1 (and a cross button to remove this filter)</div>
<div>id: val0,val1 (and a cross button to remove this filter)</div> .... so on
</div>
```

How can I achive this style as well as functionality in my demo workspace? [My Demo Fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/lxok2qw6m7)The shape of the style is elliptical

**Edit 1 - @Whatatimetobealive solution is OK, but the only major issue is he/she is not using loop, without loop it is becoming huge lines of code. Can someone implement this using loop** [Almost complete fiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/wowxz9jmv8)

Comment: How about simple `map` over the array? Is that what you need?

Comment: @Papi Can you kindly show me a demo?

Comment: But you're also looking for the completely styling for it (too looks like on the image you've provided)?

Comment: @Papi I need someone who can help me to style like this

Comment: To achieve wanted functionality you could just map over those two arrays like: `filtered[0].value.map(item=> <span>{item}</span>)`. 
Regarding the styling with irregular borders you've shown it won't be easy achievable with pure css imo. You could look for some css lib to do so (i believe there is at least one - but I don't remember the name, sorry). 
Also please consider scaling. How it should look like while 100 names are marked? It should grow vertically, horizontally? Maybe just simple background image of a div could be used, which will grow along the div?

Comment: @Papi  Not irregular, it is elliptical

Comment: oh, now it's different story. Then it's not so complicated :)

Comment: If you're interested I could prepare some simple solution when I'm done with my stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example,

https://codesandbox.io/s/ppq783nx8m

Basically, I checked the obj is null if it is not add to the names and display.

```
let first_names = null;
let last_names = null;
let first_names_label = null;
let last_names_label = null;
if (this.state.filtered.length == 1) {
  if (this.state.filtered[0].id == "firstName") {
    first_names_label = "First Name:";
  } else {
    first_names_label = "Last Name:";
  }
  first_names = this.state.filtered[0].value.map(name => <p>{name}</p>);
} else if (this.state.filtered.length == 2) {
  first_names_label = "First Name:";
  first_names = this.state.filtered[0].value.map(name => <p>{name}</p>);
  last_names_label = "Last Name:";
  last_names = this.state.filtered[1].value.map(name => <p>{name}</p>);
}

return (
  <div>
    <pre>
      {first_names_label}
      {first_names}
      {last_names_label}
      {last_names}
    </pre>
```

You can add any style as you like. Hope it helps...

Comment: Kindly make it generic - for both firstName and lastName

Comment: sure, I updated my answer please check but I did not do the styling just the logic so you can get the idea :) If you need help on styling too let me know so I will update.

Comment: Is it possible to do this using a loop? Because it is becoming huge lines of code. At one point of time, I will probably have 15 dropdowns for all columns

Comment: Also the values will be comma separated

Comment: I see, its def doable but kinda more complicated and its late here, need a sleep :), I might take a look again when I have time if no one helps.